# Initialization of an object of class/struct

Tags: c++, struct, initialization

When trying initialize an object for MyClass, I saw these two methods are used:

```
MyClass a;
MyClass a{};
```

Both cases seem to work fine, but I am wondering is there a better practice that one should use which in certain scenarios?

Comment: Without having constructor arguments, there's absolutely no difference.

Comment: What is `MyClass`? The effect is actually different for built-in types or classes without explicit constructors.

Comment: I believe `MyClass a{};` will zero initialize `a` in some cases where as `MyClass a;` won't. It depends on what `MyClass` is.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ this is not true for all types.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux not zero-initialize, but value-initialize it members.

Comment: @SergeyA Ah, yes, I see. The question needs more context though.

Comment: @SergeyA I was thinking specifically of non-class types where value initialization delegates to zero initialization.

Answer (score 3):

There is a subtle different between `MyClass a;` and `MyClass a{};`.  If `Myclass` is a [fundamental type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) or an [aggregate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) then

```
MyClass a;
```

will leave  `a`'s sate/members uninitialized while

```
MyClass a{};
```

will [value initialize](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) `a`'s state/members.

If `Myclass` is neither of the above then they will have the same behavior.

Comment: Just add a possibility of `using MyClass = int` and we will have a complete answer.

Comment: @SergeyA Updated.